# Create users as admin in Appwrite

Tags: flutter, dart, appwrite

I'm fairly new with Appwrite, that means I can work with it but not used all functions yet because I did not need them till now.
Now I need to be able to create new users when I'm logged in as admin. This users can login  at their own, and haven their own status (like customer or editor).

I must also be able to add extra profile information on that user. Like birthdate , address etc.

I followed a lot of tutorials but they are fairly old and all use the user = User(client) part. But that is not working in the Flutter Appwrite sdk. I think it has changed to Account?

Can anyone point me in the right direction how I can do all of the above and manage the users as admin and assign the extra data to them?

Comment: Have you tried using `Account(client)`?

Comment: Yes, but can this also be used as admin? Because what is the difference between Accounts and Users ? Not sure why that is divided. I understand that Accounts is for server side accounts and users is for Admin side accounts? As of the docs on Appwrite.

Answer (score 0):

in the older tutorials there were two classes named "Account" one as a service and one as a model, now the model one has been renamed to "User" which you will find in Appwrite User API documentation. You can see the difference between Account and User API using their documentation, basically User API gives you functionality like creating users (sign-up etc) and user-side actions which you allow as a Admin (which include updating name, updating e-mail as well)